# ajax error while hitting the url in controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#shorstore').DataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "ajax": "/getcomp"
        });
    });
</script>


@RequestMapping(value = "/getcomp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getComp() {
        System.out.println("Get Comp -------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    return "admin/company";
    }
```

Error

> DataTables warning: table id=shortstorage - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: What HTTP status code is your controller returning?

Comment: @gaheinrichs i have pasted controller method now..

Comment: try `return new ResponseEntity<>("admin/company", HttpStatus.OK);` What does "admin/company" do? I believe DataTables will want to receive some JSON.

Comment: What do you get if you open the url directly in the browser?   Check the browser debugging tools (F12) and familiarise yourself with how the network tab works.

Comment: @gaheinrichs *"DataTables will want to receive some JSON*" a valid point - but according to the link provided, "*DataTables will fire a specific error for the case where the request from the server is a valid return (200 Ok for example), but not valid JSON*" - so OPs *next* question will be based on the issue of it not returning JSON in the required format.

Comment: @gaheinrichs response is not getting as error comes in the page alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getcomp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Company> getComp() {
        List<Company> alist = company.findAll();

        return alist;
    }
```

Adding **@ResponseBody** to the method signature help me to get the response of the ajax call.